# MongoDB: Sharded Collections are not updating using Admin access

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to update all the collections in the User DB.

But the collections are not updating. No error also.
When I copied the User DB as User-test DB the update worked.\
Sharded key: username

What can be the issue?

I am using

```
db.User.find().forEach(function (doc) {
  doc.name = "john";
  db.User.save(doc);
})
```

Comment: What is the response you get?

Comment: Success Response. No Error.

Comment: The response should be like this: `{ "acknowledged" : true, "matchedCount" : 0, "modifiedCount" : 0, "upsertedId" : ObjectId("56fc5dcb39ee682bdc609b02") }` Please provide more details. What is your update command? We are not clairvoyant.

Comment: Yeah sorry for that. I added the query

Answer (score 0):

Method `save` is deprecated, you should not use it anymore.

Proper update would be this:

```
db.User.find().forEach(function (doc) {
  let ret = db.User.updateOne({ _id: doc._id }, {$set: {name: "john" }});
  print(tojsononeline(ret));
})
```

However, running update one-by-one will have bad performance. Even better update would be

```
db.User.updateMany({}, {$set: {name: "john" }})
```

Comment: Thanks @wernfried. I got the issue. It is because of sharding collection. From v4.2 save don't work on sharded key other than `_id`